# Is Java inlining still an issue for most JVMs?

Tags: java, android, performance, inline

In a (now) relatively old book,  ["Java Puzzlers"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X), the authors talk about the inlining problems that can occur in static final fields (Puzzle 93: Class Warfare [discussed here](http://softcycle.blogspot.de/2012/09/puzzle-93-class-warfare.html)).

Essentially Java used to have a problem where due to how classes load, you could run into the issue that if a library class (class A) is recompiled with a changed static final field, then a class (class B) which uses that field might not function properly. This could happen because the class A field might have been inlined into class B during compilation, so that when the library is updated, class B does not incorporate the change in the class A field.

My simple question is... Is this still a problem? Do the newer versions of Java redefine the class loading procedure so that we do not have to worry about such issues?

I can only find relatively old posts touching on this issue (pre-2014), which makes me think that this issue has somehow been addressed, but I can find no definitive source.

Also, if it makes any difference, I am particularly interested if this will be a problem in Android.

Comment: AFAIK, yes, it's still a problem. Compile-time constant expressions (not *all* static final fields) are inlined by the compiler.

Comment: There are also good reasons to do this inlining of constants during compile time (not during class loading), so don't expect this to be "fixed".

Comment: I understand why inlining is helpful. I just thought that maybe the build systems were improved to somehow detect this.

Comment: If you rebuild the code you are fine. The problem is only if you change some libraries (that do not provide binary compatibility) at execution time, without rebuilding the code.